# Asp.Net Core Windows Authentication Not Working in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, active-directory, .net-core, windows-authentication

Asp.Net Core doesn't seem to recognize the user from the call `context?.User?.Identity?.Name` when windows authentication is enabled and running in IIS Express or IIS.

Desired behavior: Enabling both Windows authentication and anonymous authentication in IIS and/or IIS Express, Asp.Net Core should automatically recognize the windows user.

Actual behavior: When I enable both windows and anonymous authentication in IIS or IIS Express, the user name is null. When I disable anonymous authentication or call `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`, I get a login prompt, which I don't want.

My understanding is that, even though I want to use this for Active Directory, I don't need active directory or a domain to authenticate a windows user.

Environment:

- Windows 8.1 (not on a domain)
- IIS 8.5 / Visual Studio 2017 w/ IIS Express
- Windows Authentication security feature installed
- Windows Authentication & (with NTLM provider) & Anonymous Authentication Enabled
- Logged in as local account user

Dependencies:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.8

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {                
            UserName = context?.User?.Identity?.Name
        }));
    });
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51682/",
      "sslPort": 0      
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

applicationhost.config: (IIS Express)

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/

```
<authentication>
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
  <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
  <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add value="NTLM" />
    </providers>
  </windowsAuthentication>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things:

1. When you disable anonymous authentication, you get a popup because the browser likely doesn't trust the site. You need to open Internet Options (from the Windows Control Panel) -> Security tab -> Click 'Trusted Sites' -> Click 'Sites' and add the URL to your site there. Both IE and Chrome use those settings for deciding whether to automatically send your credentials.
2. When you have *both* anonymous and Windows authentication enabled, anonymous takes precedence except in places where you tell it that the user must be logged in. To do that, use the `[Authorize]` attribute either on a controller, or just on individual actions. There are more details in the documentation, under the heading [Allow Anonymous Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth#allow-anonymous-access).

Comment: It seems the latest version of Chrome inherits settings from IE. When testing on localhost, I had to move localhost from trusted sites to local intranet zone in IE to fix the login prompt issue in both IE and Chrome. Follow these instructions on Firefox: https://docs.secureauth.com/display/KBA/Enable+Integrated+Windows+Authentication+%28IWA%29+in+Mozilla+Firefox

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have followed pretty much the step but still can not get it work. The site works if I configure it without any binding with port 8081. But if I configure the site with any binding it just keep prompting the credentials dialog and even after providing correct credentials it never goes thru. I posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213584/windows-authentication-does-not-work-on-iis-with-asp-net-core). Please suggest if there is any other way I can solve this issue.

Comment: My god thank you I've been ripping my hair out on this one

Answer (score 0):

In my case not enabled the windows authentication in the IIS server. once I enabled it's working fine.

[image]